# VStack fit content width bug on iPhone SE 1st gen

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to align two texts to left and right, respectively, to a fixed-width view, like this:

[image: layout]

I can achieve that with the following code:

```
struct VStackSpacerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 8) {
            Rectangle().fill(Color.red).frame(width: 200, height: 50)
            
            HStack {
                Text("left")
                Spacer()
                Text("right")
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
        .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
    }
}

struct VStackSpacerView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStackSpacerView()
    }
}
```

It works well most of time. However, I noticed that the layout is broken on iPhone SE 1st generation:

[image: issue]

Is this a known bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the bug is caused by the device and not the iOS version? What iOS version are you testing on?

Comment: iOS 14.5. But it's working on an iPhone 8 on the same version

Comment: What Xcode version are you building with? I can't reproduce this bug on an iPhone SE 1st gen iOS 14.5 simulator using Xcode 14.1.

Comment: Xcode 14.0.1 

Comment: I will update and check

Comment: With XCode 14.1, the problem now appears reliably on all devices running iOS 14.5. Maybe I missed that the first time. It seems indeed that the iOS version is the problem. Can't you reproduce this issue?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue either in a pure SwiftUI app, presenting this view from a `NavigationLink` or a UIKit app, where I'd present this view using a `UIHostingController`.

Comment: Well now it works on all devices in Simulator, but is broken on all devices in Preview. So I guess that this is solved